# Kendo command template show/hide on condition

Tags: javascript, templates, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I know I can set values of regular data columns within a kendo grid like this:

```
columns: [
    { field: "Test", template: "#= Test? 'test successful' : 'test failed' #" }
]
```

However, I need to set a command on a condition but when I try to do the same on a command column I get an error telling me Test would not be defined.

```
columns: [
    { field: "Test", template: "#= Test? 'test successful' : 'test failed' #" },
    { command:
        { name: "test",
          template: "#= Test? '<a class=\"k-button k-button-icontext\" title=\"Test Successful\" />' : '<a class=\"k-button k-button-icontext\" hidden />' #", click: Test
        }
    }
]
```